# How to compare different sections of a time series with each other?

Tags: time-series, simulation

I am analyzing time series showing the average delay of vehicles based on simulation time in traffic microsimulation. 5 simulation runs were performed, so there are 5 time series in the figure. I intend to compare different regions specified in this figure. I was wondering if there is a method to compare the characteristics of time series in different regions.

Thanks,
Reza.

[image]